# String[] urls won't update correctly

Tags: java, android, string

For my class we have to create an application where we catch an SMS message in a broadcast receiver, get the string (assumed to be a URL), add it dynamically to a string-array which is displayed in a fragmentlist. When the list item is clicked we then have to load it into a webview in a fragment.

Everything works until here.

The problem is that the list doesn't update when I try to add the url_act string to it.

Here's my code:

```
public class UpdateString extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String url_act = "";
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    url_act = b.getString("url");

    UrlListFragment uf = (UrlListFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);


    String[] urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.urls_array);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = Arrays.asList(urls);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    arrayList.add(url_act);
    urls = arrayList.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UpdateString.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, urls);
    uf.setListAdapter(adapter);



}
```

If you need more code for context let me know. *Updated*

Comment: Force closes come with associated stack traces, post the crash trace from the logs... My bet is that `uf` is _bull_.

Comment: I get a NullPointer Exception at: "06-07 06:00:17.058: E/AndroidRuntime(2977):  at com.connor.black.UpdateString.onCreate(UpdateString.java:37)"

Comment: Black: And _UpdateString.java_ line **37** is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should post your logcat output just to be sure, as otherwise we don't know what kind of exception was thrown.

That being said, I bet it is a `NullPointerException`; `findFragmentById()` is most likely returning `null`. This is probably because you never inflate your XML resource to begin with.

Comment: Why would findFragmentById() return null? I have a layout defined.

Comment: Yes, but you never inflate your XML layout (i.e. with `setContentView()`).

Comment: The activity's layout exist because you never inflate it... thus, the fragment doesn't exist either and is never found.

Comment: You could define the fragment in the Activity's XML layout, call `setContentView()` in your `onCreate` method, and then `findFragmentById()` should work fine. Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Adding

Comment: Your fragment is never found, and is thus never instantiated. The `onCreateView` method is never called as a result...

Comment: Ok, I commented back in the original onCreate method I have above. But now the list does not update correctly like it is supposed to.

Comment: The problem is probably that you are calling `setListAdapter` in the activity. Fragments have their own separate life cycle so it doesn't make much sense to call `setListAdapter` in the activity's `onCreate` method. You should try calling `setListAdapter` in the fragment's `onActivityCreated` method instead.